# How to add AD Security Group to Yammer private group?

Tags: yammer

I want to add AD security group to yammer private group. But When I am adding AD security group nothing is showing there. We have a yammer subscription for our organization. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Yammer does not support synchronization of Security Groups from Active Directory. Group Management (adding, removing users) happens directly in Yammer or via the REST API. Please see https://developer.yammer.com